# How to update multiple rows of a table through a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, inner-join

[Take this image of the table as the table on which I need to perform the multiple update operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIlA8.png) I have an employee table with 1000 entries, another table is the department table with 1000 entries as well. I created a mapping table which the contains the primary keys of both the tables and it also has 1000 entries. Now, I have to join all these three tables and perform update procedures to some of the rows but it should be able to update the rows in one go and that also is preferred using a stored procedure. Need some help!

I am aware about using the table variable for doing so,
But I need to understand how to write the script for creating the stored procedure and doing the same.

Thanks.

Comment: please paste example of code you tried

Comment: I do not have any idea about how to proceed, I read a lot but did not quite get it.

Comment: Start with pasting structure of input data and desired output.

Comment: You cannot literally perform the updates "in one go" because each `UPDATE` statement can only update a single table, but you can certainly have multiple statements in a procedure wrapped in a transaction. The syntax for `CREATE PROCEDURE` is documented well enough; if you need specific help you'll need to supply specific details.

Comment: What table needs to be updated? The employees, departments or mapping? Or all of them?

Comment: @RobertKock take for example any table for now, how can I update multiple rows?

Comment: @JeroenMostert using the UPDATE statement will consume a lot of time, I already tried that. is there a way to update multiple rows other than that?

Comment: T-SQL is a fairly straightforward language. The only thing that updates rows is `UPDATE` (and `MERGE`, technically, but that uses the same update mechanisms). Though `UPDATE` can only update one table, it can update as many rows in that table as you please. If your update "consumes a lot of time", there's ways to analyze and fix that (including but not limited to indexing, smarter queries and splitting it up in batches). Without details of your specific scenario it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @JeroenMostert my scenario is, I have a table named employee and I need to update multiple rows in that table. For doing so I need to create a stored procedure mostly a parametric one. I already went for that approach but it updates only one row  at the time of calling the stored procedure. Now, how to do it for multiple rows? Should I go for a loop method or is there a smarter way of doing so?

Comment: And also I used the UPDATE statement only, but I guess it only works for a single row.

Comment: `UPDATE` accepts `FROM` clauses and common table expressions (`WITH x AS (SELECT value, newvalue FROM Table) UPDATE x SET value = newvalue`) that allows you to use `JOIN`s, subqueries and whatever else you need to update all rows at once in a set-based manner. It is not restricted to updating only a single row. Again, if you have actual tables, actual data and an actual query you're using now, people can actually suggest how to rewrite what you've got.

Comment: I have attached the image of the sample table, now how update the information on multiple rows?

Comment: so as to not writing query for updating every single time for one UPDATE

Comment: @JeroenMostert I got your point, can that series of queries be written inside a stored procedure?

Comment: You're an intern - go ask the people that should be teaching you and guiding you. For future reference, just about any question you might have has been discussed somewhere on the internet. Learn to search. If you cannot find anything by searching, try the documentation. MS has rather good documentation with many examples - the [update statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#OtherTables). And if you don't know how to write a stored procedure it seems you need additional training before you start this task.

Comment: Thanks @SMor, maybe you don't know but I did search a lot. And by a lot I mean legitimate searching about the issue I was facing. I am aware about the statements and their usage and I also know how to create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have suggested in the comments, you should absolutely read up on how `UPDATE` works in SQL Server, as this will do everything it sounds like you need.

In any case, here's an example to help explain this for you. First, let's create a table `Employees` and populate it with some records:

```
create table Employees
(
    id int,
    first_name varchar(50),
    last_name varchar(50),
    starting_date date,
    last_checked date
)

insert into Employees values 
(1, 'John', 'Smith', '2016-05-16', null),
(2, 'Sandra', 'Evans', '2013-02-02', null),
(3, 'Phil', 'Jones', '2019-10-25', null),
(4, 'Jenny', 'Lewis', '2018-07-11', null),
(5, 'Steve', 'Daniels', '2018-02-28', null)
```

Now we're able to select all the rows out of this table and see the data:

```
select * from Employees

RESULTS:
/------------------------------------------------------------\
| id | first_name | last_name | starting_date | last_checked |
|----|------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 1  | John       | Smith     | 2016-05-16    | NULL         |
| 2  | Sandra     | Evans     | 2013-02-02    | NULL         |
| 3  | Phil       | Jones     | 2019-10-25    | NULL         |
| 4  | Jenny      | Lewis     | 2018-07-11    | NULL         |
| 5  | Steve      | Daniels   | 2018-02-28    | NULL         |
\------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Now, if we wanted to update every row in the table, for example to set a value in the `last_checked` column, this can be done with a simple `UPDATE` statement:

```
update Employees set last_checked = getdate()
```

This updates every record in the table:

```
select * from Employees

RESULTS:
/------------------------------------------------------------\
| id | first_name | last_name | starting_date | last_checked |
|----|------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 1  | John       | Smith     | 2016-05-16    | 2020-01-21   |
| 2  | Sandra     | Evans     | 2013-02-02    | 2020-01-21   |
| 3  | Phil       | Jones     | 2019-10-25    | 2020-01-21   |
| 4  | Jenny      | Lewis     | 2018-07-11    | 2020-01-21   |
| 5  | Steve      | Daniels   | 2018-02-28    | 2020-01-21   |
\------------------------------------------------------------/
```

If desired, you can equally use a `WHERE` clause to determine *which* records should be updated:

```
update Employees set last_checked = '2019-01-01' where starting_date <= '2019-01-01'

select * from Employees

RESULTS:
/------------------------------------------------------------\
| id | first_name | last_name | starting_date | last_checked |
|----|------------|-----------|---------------|--------------|
| 1  | John       | Smith     | 2016-05-16    | 2019-01-01   |
| 2  | Sandra     | Evans     | 2013-02-02    | 2019-01-01   |
| 3  | Phil       | Jones     | 2019-10-25    | 2020-01-21   |
| 4  | Jenny      | Lewis     | 2018-07-11    | 2019-01-01   |
| 5  | Steve      | Daniels   | 2018-02-28    | 2019-01-01   |
\------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Note how every `last_checked` date except the one for Phil Jones was updated, because of the `where starting_date <= 2019-01-01` clause in the `update` statement.

Hopefully that demonstrates the basics of an `update` statement, which can of course be wrapped in a Stored Procedure if you need:

```
create procedure [dbo].[updateEmployeeLastChecked] 
    @newDate date = null
as

if @newDate is null set @newDate = getdate()
update Employees set last_checked = @newDate where starting_date <= @newDate
```

So in this instance, the stored procedure takes an optional parameter (which defaults to the current date if not supplied) specifying the date to be used when updating the records in the `Employees` table, provided the date specified is after the `starting_date` for each employee. Not a particularly useful or realistic procedure, but it demonstrates the principle hopefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am sure this will help.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote the answer if you find it useful.